# SocketTimeoutException in hadoop fs -getmerge

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I'm running hadoop fs -getmerge and getting the following error:

```
12/10/30 09:24:45 INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Failed to connect to /[IP], add to
deadNodes and continue
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be   
ready for read. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel
```

I'm getting this error with different IP each try and I don't see any suspicious error or warning in the data node logs.

any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

HDFS reads are done directly from the block holding DataNodes.

A common reason behind this, especially if it is consistent in failure this way, is the lack of proper Client ➜ DataNode connectivity, owing to firewalls or other reasons.